# Android make expandable listview

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I'm making an expandable listview in Android.
ListView has 10 items.
I have a button show More/Less, when click this button I want to expand/collapse from position 2 to position 9 (not collapse to 0 as default ExpandableListView.java). And have animation.
Can you help me! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

**`Animated Expanding ListView`** provides a fancy animation on expanding or collapsing the content of a list view item . Please check this [AnimatedExpandableListView](https://github.com/idunnololz/AnimatedExpandableListView/)

Comment: Thank you, but default is collapsing all items. I want to collapse to position 2.

Comment: I want: 
when expanded: show 10 items
when collapsed: show 2 items